# Einstein Analytics multiple derivedMeasures

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

I am able to to make this code for the derivedMeasures in the xmd.json for work to rename the count of rows in a chart. However, when I try to add a second count or sum anywhere else in the dashboard, the dataset prevents me from adding any additional counts or sums except for the Count of Total Candidates. Can I, and if so, how do I add multiple derivedMeasures to this file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you don't provide a name for the derived Dimension, so EA uses it for all, cause all do aplly to *.

Try going into the SAQL and rename 'count' to 'countCandidates'.
Then update the "Field" value in the xmd to countCandidate.
Accordingly do the same for other sums and counts.

Alternatively (if you don't want to go to SAQL) you can go into the compare table, click the triangle of your count colum and then "Edit this column". Here you cann apply a Header for each column individually.

Option 1 has the advantage, that it is reusable for every dashboard which uses that dataset and needs a "Total Candidates" Column, while option 2 lets you keep using the visual interface to modify the table.